# Getting variables in the subdomain URL with htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, variables

I need that when I write http://username123.mysite.com/ the username is sent as a parameter to user.php

example: http://www.mysite.com/user.php?user=username123

how can I do with htaccess? you have other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

when you create the a tag to go to the user.php page, in the href just do this

```
<a href='user.php?user=".$row['username']."'></a>
```

assuming you have SQL Queries and all that stuff to get details from a db

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this with .htaccess if your web server is Apache with Mod_Rewrite.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*).mysite.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www).mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/user.php?username=%1 [R=301,L]

The first rewrite condition and rule are to force people who use mysite.com to www.mysite.com and can be removed (just an SEO trick).

The last 2 rewrite conditions and associated rule should be roughly what you are looking for. All of my webservers are currently in production mode, so I can't try this out.